# Windows 8 Keyboard Connected event

Tags: windows-8, keyboard

Is there any API in Windows 8 that tells you whether there is a Keyboard connected to your device? I believe the OS should have information about this, but I am not sure that it is exposed.

I checked the `Windows.Devices.Input.KeyboardCapabilities()`. It only returns an object with a property `keyboardPresent` that equals to 1 on my touch device or non-touch device.

Answer (score 0):

The problem has already been reported on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12841218/windows-8-winrt-keyboardcapabilities-keyboardpresent-is-always-true) without solution (Provide another solution but which also don't seem to work).

Maybe a work around could be to add a TextBox outside the screen and set the focus on it and register InputPane.GetForCurrentView().Showing and to see if it is fired or not. If it is you can deduce that there is no keyboard connected (and you might be able to reset the focus to the page inside the event so that the keyboard don't actually pop up) and if it don't fired that the there is a keyboard connected. That not a really good solution but might be the best available ...

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. For my use case, I can check mousePresent as well. But it is annoying that KeyboarPresent just doesn't do the right thing